# jquery raty plugin not working with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, raty

I'm running rails 3.2, and trying to add a rating system using this: http://wbotelhos.com/raty/.

For some reason, even though I've added:

```
 $('#rating').raty();
```

to my script, and

```
 <div id="rating"></div>
```

to my html as shown at the website, I still can't see the stars.

I've added:

```
 //= require jquery.raty
```

to my application.js, and have jquery.raty.js in my javascripts folder.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried using a gem: https://github.com/bmc/jquery-raty-rails and that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the photos for the stars? 
Make sure that you have star-on.png and star-off.png in assets/images
Also, add the following code in your html.erb file,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#rating").raty({
            path: '/assets/'
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the javascript call:

```
$('#star').raty();
```

in order to get

```
<div id="star"></div>
```

to show.